# multi-tenant with eclipse link

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement a multitenant architecture, using eclipselink. I have a table Entidade, the name of the Entidade will be the tenant. I have a Usuario table, where each usuario is connected to an Entidade. The table Usuario and Entidade have a tenant default, because when login with a Usuario, I have no way to know which Entidade that Usuario belongs. By inserting the entities in the database, does not give any problem. The problem is to query the user class, especially when the search is made of the child class, Entidade, throw the following exception:

```
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2013-09-18 11:39:50.976--ServerSession(20689274)--The tenant discriminator context property for the tenant discriminator column [USUARIO.id_tenant] on the element [class teste.Usuario] is being defaulted to: eclipselink.tenant-id.
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2013-09-18 11:39:50.993--ServerSession(20689274)--The tenant discriminator context property for the tenant discriminator column [ENTIDADE.id_tenant] on the element [class teste.Entidade] is being defaulted to: eclipselink.tenant-id.
[EL Info]: 2013-09-18 11:39:51.604--ServerSession(20689274)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2013-09-18 11:39:51.823--ServerSession(20689274)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [entidade] for the entity class [class teste.Usuario] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Info]: connection: 2013-09-18 11:39:51.894--ServerSession(20689274)--file:/D:/java/workspaceweb/TesteTenant/bin/_teste login successful
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-09-18 11:39:51.93--ServerSession(20689274)--Connection(29390792)--SELECT id_usuario, id_tenant, nome, id_entidade FROM USUARIO WHERE (id_tenant = ?)
    bind => [usuario]
[EL Warning]: 2013-09-18 11:39:51.957--ServerSession(20689274)--Exception [EclipseLink-6174] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: No value was provided for the session property [eclipselink.tenant-id]. This exception is possible when using additional criteria or tenant discriminator columns without specifying the associated contextual property. These properties must be set through Entity Manager, Entity Manager Factory or persistence unit properties. If using native EclipseLink, these properties should be set directly on the session.
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readEntidade" referenceClass=Entidade sql="SELECT id_entidade, id_tenant, nome FROM ENTIDADE WHERE ((id_entidade = ?) AND (id_tenant = ?))")
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6174] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: No value was provided for the session property [eclipselink.tenant-id]. This exception is possible when using additional criteria or tenant discriminator columns without specifying the associated contextual property. These properties must be set through Entity Manager, Entity Manager Factory or persistence unit properties. If using native EclipseLink, these properties should be set directly on the session.
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readEntidade" referenceClass=Entidade sql="SELECT id_entidade, id_tenant, nome FROM ENTIDADE WHERE ((id_entidade = ?) AND (id_tenant = ?))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:479)
    at teste.TesteBuscaMain.main(TesteBuscaMain.java:29)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6174] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: No value was provided for the session property [eclipselink.tenant-id]. This exception is possible when using additional criteria or tenant discriminator columns without specifying the associated contextual property. These properties must be set through Entity Manager, Entity Manager Factory or persistence unit properties. If using native EclipseLink, these properties should be set directly on the session.
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readEntidade" referenceClass=Entidade sql="SELECT id_entidade, id_tenant, nome FROM ENTIDADE WHERE ((id_entidade = ?) AND (id_tenant = ?))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.missingContextPropertyForPropertyParameterExpression(QueryException.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ParameterExpression.getValue(ParameterExpression.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.translate(DatabaseCall.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2777)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2730)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneFromRow(ObjectBuilder.java:1948)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    ... 1 more
```

the class that create a EntityManagerFactory and the EntityManager:

```
public class JPAUtil {

    private static JPAUtil instance = null;

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityTransaction transaction;

    private static ThreadLocal entityManagers = new ThreadLocal();

    static {
        instance = new JPAUtil();
    }

    private JPAUtil() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PUAequalis");
    }

    public static JPAUtil getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new JPAUtil();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void openEntityManager(String tenant) {
        if (entityManagers == null || entityManagers.get() == null
                || !entityManagers.get().isOpen()) {
            HashMap properties = new HashMap();

            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.setProperty("eclipselink.tenant-id", tenant);
            em.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenant);
            entityManagers.set(em);

        } else {
            closeOpenEntityManager(tenant);
        }
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagers.get();
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager() {

        if (entityManagers != null && entityManagers.get().isOpen()) {
            entityManagers.get().close();
        }
    }

    public static void closeOpenEntityManager(String tenant) {
        if (entityManagers != null && entityManagers.get().isOpen()) {
            entityManagers.get().close();
            entityManagers.remove();
            HashMap properties = new HashMap();
            properties.put("eclipselink.tenant-id", tenant);
            entityManagers.set(emf.createEntityManager(properties));
        }
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf != null && emf.isOpen()) {
            emf.close();
        }
    }

    public EntityTransaction getTransaction() {
        if (transaction == null || !transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction = entityManagers.get().getTransaction();
        }
        return transaction;
    }

}
```

the persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="teste" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider> org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache"
                value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" /> -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and de Entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Multitenant
    @TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "id_tenant")
    public class Entidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8179478584980079687L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_entidade", length = 10)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idEntidade;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "id_tenant", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String idTenant;

    ...get and setters

}
```

```
    @Entity
    @Multitenant
    @TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "id_tenant")
    public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8956344014336399968L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_usuario", length = 10)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idUsuario;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name = "nomeCompleto")
    private String nomeCompleto;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "tipo_usuario")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoUsuario tipoUsuario;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, targetEntity = Entidade.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entidade")
    private Entidade entidade;

    @Column(name = "id_tenant", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String idTenant;

    ...get and setters
    }
```

has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Does the problem still occur if weaving is used?  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving  weaving is required to implement lazy on your OneToOne mappings.  The error shows the issue occurs when trying to eagerly fetch the entidade reference, so weaving might either fix the issue, or delay it until you access the relationship.   You might still want it for performance reasons even if it doesn't help with this error though.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you need to set the context-property with the tenant value AFTER the begin of transaction.

http://codecrafters.blogspot.it/2013/03/multi-tenant-cloud-applications-with.html

Let me know...

Comment: Is it possible to turn off Multi-Tenancy without any change?. that means Even I annotated Entity with @Multi-Tenant annotation and even there is a column TENANT_ID in database, but if I does not set PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT than it should not throw exception and any CRUD operation should be success.